# Rails 4 - Parentheses in Rails parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using AJAX to sumit a form to a Ruby method. I have automatically-generated form names with parentheses. Reading the params works for one without the parentheses, but won't read the ones with (obviously). Escaping the parentheses doesn't seem to work. How would I read these in the controller using `params[]`

**Controller:**

```
  def add
    @name = params[:item][:name]
    @expiration_month = params[:item][:expiration(2i)]

    result = { :name => @name, :expiration => @expiration_month }
    render :json => result, :status => :ok
  end
```

**Rails console output**:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"Dw7aqaIuk3btP+Alp03AXgDjoJyK2YoZH2CDo6LEPzM=", "item"=>{"name"=>"cvbnvbncv", "expiration(2i)"=>"", "expiration(3i)"=>"", "expiration(1i)"=>"", "classification_id"=>""}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u can do it this way also

```
@expiration_month = params["item"]["expiration(2i)"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be other ways to do this, but the first that pops in to my head is to create a string representation first, then turn it in to a symbol using [`to_sym`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_sym), like so:

```
@expiration_month = params[:item]["expiration(2i)".to_sym]
```

Technically speaking, the main downside (which probably won't be an issue in your case), is having to create that string object. Since strings are mutable and not auto-interned as they are in other languages like Java, doing the `"expiration(2i)".to_sym` line will in fact produce two strings objects, despite them having the same character sequence. Again, I doubt this will be a problem for you, given the code you posted, but thought I would mention it regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to accept Rahul's answer because it functionally does the same thing and my use case doesn't require a conversion because I am only using the parameter for one request.

Comment: @Patrick No worries at all. This is precisely how accepted answer selection should work. And his answer does make more sense; I forgot you can access with a plain string as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to say without further context, but I'd suggest assigning `expiration(2i)` to a variable and then passing in the variable.